# Indentation Error in the Usage of 'def' in Python 3.7

Tags: python, indentation, python-3.7

```
def day_display_control(entered_variable,controlling_number,return_message):
    if entered_variable == controlling_number:
        return(return_message)
```

I have been trying to find a problem here, as IDLE keeps on giving an indentation error saying **expected an indented block** yet I have found none so far, my indentation width is 4 and I tried using only tab as well, haven't found the solution, thank you in advance as this is probably a really basic question.

P.S:
  I have also tried to debug the rest of the code without this line, yet while this gives the same error:

```
def day_display():
    day_display_number = day % 7
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,0,Monday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,1,Thuesday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,2,Wednesday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,3,Thursday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,4,Friday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,5,Saturday)
    day_display = day_diplay_control(day_display_number,6,Sunday)
```

Do not mind the quality of the code, the problem is that previous 'def's don't cause this to happen, such as;

```
def typeWait(message,delay):
    message = str(message)
    print(message)
    sleep(delay)
```

P.P.S: I have just realized, as of yesterday, that python was not 3.6 anymore, but instead 3.7 alpha 2, which leads me to believe that this is either a new feature or a bug, I have found no articles about either of them yet, so if anyone knows what the problem is, I would appriciate it a lot.

Comment: If it's giving the "expected an indented block" on the `def` line itself, that's likely a problem with the preceding code - an `if:` with no indented body under it, for example.

Comment: That indeed is the case, yet the only thing under if is the 'return', which is indented, and this def only consists of this 'if' block

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @jasonharper. Check if you mistyped `=` instead of `==`, and also if any of these are missing: `)`, `]` or `}`. It might not be near the block of these functions.